# Restore 64 Bit Database to 32 Bit Database SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, 32bit-64bit

At My Customer Site they have 
--SQL Server 2008 R2 64Bit Express Edition Installed on Server 2008 OS Machine
at My Development environment i have
-- 32Bit Vista Machine and Sql Server 2008 Express Edition Installed

My Question is how can restore back up of 64bit DB to My 32 bit DB

What i tried
1) Create the Back up of 64 Bit DB and Create DB on my 32 Bit Machine and Restore it 
i get an error

Restore failed for Server 'egov041\SQLEXPRESS2008'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.1600. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 10.00.2531. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

2) Copy the MDF and LDF File from the Server Machine 
and Attach it on my machine

i get an error

Attach database failed for Server 'egov041\SQLEXPRESS2008'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

The database 'PwdMhToll' cannot be opened because it is version 661. This server supports version 655 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
Could not open new database 'PwdMhToll'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 948)

i refer 
1) http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlexpress/thread/49f0adf1-8254-4e4a-b7ce-d9406d0ab6d6

2) http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/03/27/sql-server-32-bit-64-bit-html5-database-backup-restore/

3) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cindygross/archive/2010/04/01/moving-data-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-sql-server-instances.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

From these post i concluded that it is possible, 
does anybody suggest what is wrong with my database restore...
Thanks in Advance

Comment: This belongs on Database Administrators SE. (http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Best way i found to do this is to Generate the script of Database and execute it on other machine, this solved my problem
for complete steps please refer 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/21/sql-server-2005-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects

Answer (score 3):

Your issue isn't with the 32-bit vs. 64-bit, but it's that you are trying to restore/attach a database on an older version.

If you want to accomplish this, the best way is to script out your database (both schema and data) and then run the script on the destination instance.

Answer (score 2):

> The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.1600.
>   That version is incompatible with this server, which is running
>   version 10.00.2531.

This implies strongly that the source DB is 2008 R2, and your local installed version is 2008 (not R2).